# Ansible loop in loop

Tags: ansible

How can I create config files for postgres clusters with any filenames in ansible (v1.9) playbook ?
Example:

```
postgres:
  clusters:
    - name: new
      configs:
        - filename: "someconfig.1"
          template: "path.1"
        - filename: "someconfig.2"
          template: "path.2"
    - name: new2
      configs:
        - filename: "someconfig.1"
          template: "path.1"
        - filename: "someconfig.2"
          template: "path.2"
```

I want to do:

```
- name: Create configs for postgres clusters
  template: src={{ item.template }} dest={{ cluster.name }}/{{ item.filename }}
  with_items: item.configs
  with_items: postgres.clusters as cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
- name: Update configs for clusters
    sudo: yes
    sudo_user: postgres
    tags:
      - postgres
      - clusters
    template:
      src={{ item.1.template }}
      dest={{ postgres.config_dir }}/{{ item.0.version|default(postgres.version) }}/{{ item.0.name }}/{{ item.1.filename }}
      mode={{ item.1.mode|default("0600") }}
    with_subelements:
      - postgres.clusters
      - configs
    when: item.0.enable|default(true)|bool
```